# to hide a column in grid-view for "Stockcontroller" and make it visible for "Administrator"

Tags: c#, sql

This is my grideview code:

I need to use a if statment for this code:  `private const string select_query` 
need to show the first code to the Administrator and the second code to the stockcontroller. i am trying to hide only one column the last `"UserID"`.
i dont know how to call that and sign to different users using a if statement.
just tried it out!!!

this is my stock grid-view code:

```
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" Select * from New_User where User_Name=@USER_ID", conn);
selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("USER_ID", txtusername.Text.ToString());               

string UserType = null;
SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
bool rowfound = reader.HasRows;
if (rowfound)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        UserType = reader["User_Type"].ToString().Trim();

        if (UserType == "Administrator")
        {
            GlobalVariablesClass.VariableOne = txtusername.Text;

            private const string select_query = "SELECT TOP 3 id,stock_type,stock_no,no_of_pieces,Gem_Type,Weight,Image,Cost,Create_Date,Update_Date,UserID FROM Stock_Gems";

        }
        else if (UserType == "StockController")

        {
            GlobalVariablesClass.VariableOne = txtusername.Text;
            private const string select_query = "SELECT TOP 3 id,stock_type,stock_no,no_of_pieces,Gem_Type,Weight,Image,Cost,Create_Date,Update_Date FROM Stock_Gems";
        }
    }
}
```

This is my login code:

```
private void tbnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" Select * from New_User where User_Name=@USER_ID and Password=@PASS", conn);
        selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("USER_ID", txtusername.Text.ToString()));
        String password = "";

        using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
        {
            byte[] data = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtpassword.Text));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
            {
                sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            password = sb.ToString();
        }

        selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PASS", password));
        string UserType = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        bool rowfound = reader.HasRows;
        if (rowfound)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                UserType = reader["User_Type"].ToString().Trim();
                if (UserType == "Administrator")
                {
                    GlobalVariablesClass.VariableOne = txtusername.Text;
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "Admin Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    Admin_Menu frm = new Admin_Menu();
                    frm.bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = true;
                    frm.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else if (UserType == "StockController")
                {
                    GlobalVariablesClass.VariableOne = txtusername.Text;
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "User Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    Admin_Menu frm = new Admin_Menu();
                    frm.bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = false;
                    frm.Show();                         
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }

            }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Invalid User Or Password ", "Login ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

I have a grid-view with columns of items as follows:

```
ID|Stock_Type|Stock_No|No_of_pieces|Gem_Type|Weight|Image|Cost|Create_Date|Update_date|UserID|
```

I found this but I don't know how retrieve from database.

This was coded into the stock gridview loader

```
DisplayData();
hello.Text = GlobalVariablesClass.VariableOne;

if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
{
    this.dataGridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;
}
else
{
    this.dataGridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
}
```

**I have used the global variation which means the username who logged in will be on all the pages..

Comment: You don't need to change the query for your datagrid. You just need to put a condition upon displaying your datagrid. If its an admin then proceed with the normal, if not just hide the last column.

Comment: how to hide that

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false; OR dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false; just replace the index or the column name

Comment: i have updated with a code as you say, its not functioning

Comment: I tried editing your post with some format for readability and I added a closing `"` to the first code block: `" Select * from New_User where User_Name=@USER_ID"`. Please review if this reflects your actual code. Normally a missing `"` shouldn't happen when you copy-paste, so I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Note you partly ask an GUI question but you didn't mention what kind of UI framework you are using (WPF, WinForms, Web, ...)

Comment: its a winform and i am using visual studio 2015 and the database i am using sql server 2014.

Comment: @grek40 no sir its not reflecting